# Magento 2.2.5 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined

Tags: magento2, theme, console

Installed Magento 2.2.5 with sample data, everything works fine. Added a new theme Ves Need theme, got the below issues on the home page console.

> 1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined
> 2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined

Due to this, the subcategory dropdown on the nav bar not working.

Kindly help us to fix this.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Comment: how can i update jqueryui to 1.12.1 on magento 2.3? with npm or composer, its my first project magento 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated jquery-ui from 1.10 to 1.12 above errors has been resolved.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152990)

Comment: @ManashviBirla The above answer is working great for mine. That's why posted as an answer.

Comment: @ManashviBirla thanks a lot !!!!